# Phonegap google map plugin only showing a blank screen

Tags: cordova, google-maps, phonegap-plugins

I am using the phonegap google map plugin, I use the online phonegap to build my apk.

Just wondering where My config.xml should sit in the root directory, res/xml or www directory.

Also where should my index.xml sit in the root directory or www directory.

Also where should the ".cordova.CORDOVA" file sit, I have in the same directory as my index.html and at the top of the
index.html file I have the code

< script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">< /script>

This code accesses the ".cordova.CORDOVA" file. Without this code in the index.html file I get nothing, no google map screen at all.

Also where should the following files sit. I have them in my root directory.

- AndroidManifest.xml
- package.json
- plugin.xml

also if I could get a copy of someone's index.html where javascript file declarations at the top of your index.html and also a copy of AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml files would be great.

At the moment I am getting a blank screen, but the google logo appears in the lower left hand corner.

I am new to phonegap so please bear with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you develop a cordova app then do your developing only in the root of your project. For building and modifying the app only use the command line interface (Cli).

All the files you describe above are sitting in the right place.

Have you given the div of your map a absolute height and width? Something like 1000px / 600px? Relative things do not work.

Comment: Hi Joerg, the div I use has absolute values 300px / 300px. The reasons why I am asking about the positions is because the plugin.xml references the config.xml file as being in the res/xml directory.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the link to the plugin you are using?

IT would be really great if you switched from PhoneGap Build to Cordova CLI.

For Google Maps try importing it using the javascript import rather than a plugin. There is Google Maps API for Javascript.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Hi incorelabs.....I have tried the javascript that you said and it does not work on an Android mobile phone which is where I am trying to get google maps working.

Comment: I use < script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">< /script> in my index.html which gives me a blank google maps screen and if I do not include it I do even get a google map's screen. - I had previously tried the javascript on my pc web browser and it works fine there but not on my android mobile phone

Comment: Have you tried using the cordova cli? If you have not, use it and then debug ur app via gapdebug or chrome://inspect

Comment: I'll post a sample hopefully by today.. But I'll be using the cordova CLI.

Comment: Have you tried this troubleshooting document:

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/TroubleShooting:-Blank-Map